# How to specify datasource in spark.read.format when using the data direct jdbc driver of Greenplum (greenplum.jar) to read a greenplum table?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, greenplum

I am trying to read data from a table on Greenplum using spark. I wrote the code as below:

```
  val yearDF = spark.read.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider").option("url", connectionUrl)
    .option("server.port","5432")
    .option("dbtable", "tablename")
    .option("dbschema","schemaname")
    .option("user", devUserName)
    .option("password", devPassword)
    .option("partitionColumn","employeeLoc")
    .option("partitions",450)
    .load()
    .where("period_year=2017 and period_num=12")
    .select(gpColSeq map col:_*)
    .withColumn(flagCol, lit(0))
```

I am using `greenplum.jar`, which provdes the data direct jdbc driver to read data from a greenplum table using Spark.
I am using the below spark-submit command:

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION=2 spark-submit --class com.partition.source.YearPartition --master=yarn --conf spark.ui.port=4090 --driver-class-path /home/hdpuser/jars/greenplum.jar,/home/hdpuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --conf spark.jars=/home/hdpuser/jars/greenplum.jar,/home/hdpuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar --executor-cores 3 --executor-memory 13G --keytab /home/hdpuser/hdpuser.keytab --principal hdpuser@devuser.COM --files /usr/hdp/current/spark2-client/conf/hive-site.xml,testconnection.properties --name Splinter --conf spark.executor.extraClassPath=/home/hdpuser/jars/greenplum.jar,/home/hdpuser/jars/postgresql-42.1.4.jar splinter_2.11-0.1.jar
```

When I submit the jar, I see the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:553)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass$lzycompute(DataSource.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.providingClass(DataSource.scala:89)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:304)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:178)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:146)
    at com.partition.source.YearPartition$.prepareFinalDF$1(YearPartition.scala:154)
    at com.partition.source.YearPartition$.main(YearPartition.scala:181)
    at com.partition.source.YearPartition.main(YearPartition.scala)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:782)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:180)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:119)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider.DefaultSource
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(DataSource.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22$$anonfun$apply$14.apply(DataSource.scala:537)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22.apply(DataSource.scala:537)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$$anonfun$22.apply(DataSource.scala:537)
    at scala.util.Try.orElse(Try.scala:84)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource$.lookupDataSource(DataSource.scala:537)
```

I understood that this is due to using ***io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider*** in the datasource statement i.e.

> spark.read.format("io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider")

I tried "io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider" & "greenplum" but both result in the same exception which is:

> ```
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source:
> ```
>
> io.pivotal.greenplum.spark.GreenplumRelationProvider. Please find
>   packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html

I am unable to think of what should I give as my datasource in the statement `spark.read.format` while using the data direct jdbc jar: greenplum.jar

Could anyone let me know how can I fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

what version of the greenplum-spark connector are you using?

you should be able to specify the custom jdbc driver in the "driver" option.  refer to http://greenplum-spark.docs.pivotal.io/160/using_the_connector.html#use_custom_jdbcdriver.

you can specify the data source as follows:

`spark.read.format("greenplum")`